# Multiple Notifications in android is not working

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am trying to display multiple notifications for my android application using the below code. Basically both these functions are inside a service which is scheduled to be called every 20 seconds. I have given unique codes for the request code inside the pending intent and also I have given unique values for the notify ID(same as request code). All I get is one notifications (the one from the first function). Could you please tell me whether I am missing something here? Thank you.

```
public void Leavenotification(Context ctx) {

    leaveContent = new HttpReq(this,
            "some URL to be called")
            .get();

    //this.ctx = ctx;

    if (leaveContent != null) {
        leaveBean = new ToApproveLeaveBean(leaveContent, leaves);

        for (int i = 0; i < leaveBean.approveStringList.size(); i++) {
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Sample App", when);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notifyayout);
            contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notifyTitle, "New Leave Request");
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notifyText, leaveBean.approveStringList.get(leaveBean.approveStringList.size()-1));
            notification.contentView = contentView;

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; //Do not clear the notification
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

            mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);

        }
    }
}

public void Timesheetnotification(Context ctx) {

    leaveContent = new HttpReq(this,
            "some URL to be called")
            .get();

    //this.ctx = ctx;

    System.out.println("tscontent: " + leaveContent);

    if (leaveContent != null) {
        tsBean = new ToApproveTSBean(leaveContent, timesheets);

        System.out.println("c1: " + tsBean.approveStringList.size()
                + "LeaveBean: " + tsBean.isStatus);

        for (int i = 0; i < tsBean.approveStringList.size(); i++) {
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Sample app", when);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notifyayout);
            contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notifyTitle, "New Timesheet Request");
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notifyText, tsBean.approveStringList.get(tsBean.approveStringList.size()-1));
            notification.contentView = contentView;

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
            //notificationIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
            //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            PendingIntent contentIntent =
                      PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1,
                              notificationIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; //Do not clear the notification
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer to avoid confusion.  Do you get the first 2 print message from the Timesheet function ? "tscontent..." and "c1:....."

Comment: Not sure about the function calls because it does print the tscontent and c1:

Comment: I am calling the two functions inside ScheduleAtFixedRate module. I think this might be the problem.

Comment: showing how many notification controlled by id in NotificationManager.notifi(id, Notification)
if you put the same value for id every time you call notify, the previous notification will be replaced with the new one, 
maybe you could find out where went wrong by printing id before calling notify